# Delays meteor function loading

Tags: javascript, meteor

i have in my html (meteor web application):

```
{{#each GetTasks _id}}
```

This runs the GetTasks function for each _id (there is another each loop on top).
So if i have 5 items it will run GetTasks 5 times. Each function GetTasks returns something like

```
return Tasks.find({some query});
```

Is there anyway to delay the GetTasks for some of the 5 times, for instance the 3rd and 4th?I want to start presenting information for the 1st,2nd and 5th faster and then after a timeout load the information about the 3rd and 4rth (like immitating lazy-delayed load style).
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a crazy requirement, but I think this can be done either with:

1. A custom, published collection
2. A local reactive var

I think 2. is probably easier, so I'll try to describe this.

```
//...
GetTasks: function (id) {
    // Establishes reactive dependency
    var tasks = Tasks.find({some query}).fetch();
    // Use empty object as initial values
    var reactives = tasks.map(function (task) { return new ReactiveVar(task); });
    // Now reactives[0] corresponds to task 1, reactives[1] to task 2, etc.
    // Unset any values you want to appear later:
    reactives[3].set({});
    reactives[4].set({});
    // Schedule them to be set later (using 5 seconds here)
    Meteor.setTimeout(function () {
        reactives[3].set(task[3]);
        reactives[4].set(task[4]);
    }, 5000);
    return reactives.map(function (r) { return r.get(); });
}
```

This will run *every time* task data is published from the server and it matches your query.  This means you'll set a timeout each time.

Probably what you want to do is:

- track what timeouts have been set
- each time GetTasks runs check if you've already set a timeout for that task or not
- decide whether you want to override it, or leave it

Keep in mind that the old timeout will retain the old value.  If the new run provides a new value, the old value may be stale.

Also note, in the implementation I have given the old tasks are not retained.  You will probably want to do this if the position of tasks may change - for instance if tasks are deleted.  You can then test for changes in old vs. new and decide what to do.